# jQuery resizable container with dymanic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resizable

I'm creating a template editor and I created a couple of sections. I'm using jQuery for resizing this sections like this:

```
$( ".header-area" ).resizable({
        handles: 's',
        maxHeight: 500
    });
```

What happens now is that when I resize the section it's possible to make the section smaller then the content in that section.

Is it possible to resize the section till the content is reached? (The content is draggable, so there's no exact height of the sections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting css to `display:table;` for .header-area can resolve your issue.